# Recruiting Coordinator asked when my last day at my current job is

Tags: new-job, resignation

I recently received an offer (well, actually almost a month ago), and after a lengthy background check, the recruiting coordinator finally asked when my last day at my current job is.

Now I'm thinking of putting in my two weeks, but I'm thinking of telling the recruiting coordinator that my last day is in three weeks. That way I can decompress for a week and prep for the next job.

I'm hesitant to do that though, considering that the recruiting coordinator specifically asked when my last day will be and didn't ask when I can start my new job. I believe she worded it that way so she can check (via background check / paystubs) when I actually stopped working at my current job.

If that is the case, then I might just put in my two weeks (last day will be a Wed) and tell the recruiting coordinator that I'll start the following Monday. Hopefully that's fine.

Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would say that my last day is X date but that I am taking a short holiday at that time and will be available to start on Y date.

Then you are answering their question while also making it known when you want to start, without lying.

If they really need you to start earlier they will try to negotiate the start date with you, in which case you can decide when to start based on your needs and their needs.

Comment: "I can start at date x" is an acceptable answer too if you think the recruiter will try to persuade you to start earlier.

Comment: And it probably helps to start at the start of a pay period in my case the first working day of the month.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you don't know when your last day of your current job will be. Many companies, once you resign, won't want you to stick around for 2 weeks. They may walk you out that day. Therefore, you can honestly tell the recruiter that you don't know when the last day will be, but you're confident you can start [`3 weeks from now`].

With that said, it sounds like you may have a verbal offer, but not a written one. Perhaps the recruiter is shuffling candidates partly due to availability. I'd strongly advise against quitting your current job until the signed, written offer is in hand.